# Once a user is logged in go back to app (WebKit, swift, json)

Tags: swift, api, oauth, spotify

I am trying to close the WebKit browser once a user is authenticated. I built a back end rails API that my swift front-end is making requests to. My rails API responds with credentials about the user.

```
struct LoginView: UIViewRepresentable {

  let request: URLRequest

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
     return WKWebView()
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
      uiView.load(request)
  }
   
  func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ uiView: LoginView) {
     if let text = uiView.request.url?.absoluteString{
         print("THIS IS THE URL \(text)")
     }
  }

}
```

My API gives back JSON with credentials key (contains token) and if there is a credentials key in the response, I'd like to return back to my app since the user will be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following delegate method of WKWebView to get callback & move back to the app.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
      if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
              print(url.absoluteString)
              if url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("your_url"){
                  // Authenticated, remove webview and back to app
                  self.stopLoading()
           }
      }
      decisionHandler(.allow)
   }

    func stopLoading() {
        webView.removeFromSuperview()
        //Move to view controller
        // Load & push/present your view controller here
    }
```

Let me know if it solves your problem. Happy to help more.

Comment: Thank you Shashank, I'm pretty new to swift and mobile developing in general. I put these methods in a struct and now I'm getting this error "Type 'LoginView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'"

Comment: @Quin I think you should  look into this https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-use-webkit-webview-in-swiftui-4b944d04190a